# Transformer overheating issue

Tags: transformer, overheat

I have been using a 500 VA step down transformer, whose primary voltage is 2 phase 415 V and secondary voltage is 230 V. The issue is that the windings are getting overheated, without being overloaded i.e the allowable limit is 2 A and the current being drawn from transformer is 0.37 A.

What may be the possible reason for this problem?

Comment: How do you know it's overheated? It might be designed to run hot.

Comment: wrongly connected windings? Transformer itself faulty? Measure current and voltage both sides, and see if the VI products are reasonably close.

Comment: Is there a short between some "turn" of the transformer?

Comment: @Drew Smoke is coming out of the transformer.

Comment: `primary [is] 2 phase` Show a picture, preferably with a label readable? What voltage/frequency when it got hotter than you like?

Answer (score 0):

> *The issue is that the windings are getting overheated, without being
> overloaded i.e. the allowable limit is 2 A and the current being drawn
> from transformer is 0.37 A.*

If the transformer is believed to be otherwise OK then, it's probably the magnetic core that is overheating and transferring heat to the windings. Magnetic cores will overheat when the applied voltage gets too high. This type of over-heating is slightly worse in a no-secondary-load scenario.

> *What may be the possible reason for this problem?*

I can't be 100% but, it sounds like core saturation is the problem.